# "See that" vs "See something V-ed"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, sense-verbs

Is there any difference between these two constructions, for example, can I paraphrase sentence (1) as (2)?

1. She saw him killed last night.
2. She saw (that) he was killed last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No both sentences have the same meaning, although the first sentences places a very slight more emphasis on him being killed, and the second sentences places a slight emphasis on the sighting of him being killed. Otherwise both are interchangeably used.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence 2 is ambiguous. It could be that he was killed last night, and she saw that. Or it could be that he had been killed earlier, and it was last night that she saw that (e.g. she saw his dead body).

Your sentence 1 can have the first of those meanings. But it can't really have the second, because if that's what the speaker meant, they'd have probably said something different, e.g. "She saw him dead last night" or "She saw his dead body last night".

Comment: (2) could even mean that she saw from a newspaper report or the TV news that he had been killed.